# Accessing dynamically typed member

Tags: objective-c, dynamic, typing

I have a dynamically typed member `id currentEvent` in my view controller class. The rationale is that the view controller is used to display data for two model classes that are very similar.

I have a setter:

```
-(void)setCurrentEvent:(id)e {
    [self.currentEvent release];
    Class eventClass = [e class];
    currentEvent = [[eventClass alloc] init];
    currentEvent = [e retain];
}
```

Now I want to access a member of the class:

```
    return [currentEvent.comments count];
```

But the compiler complains: `request for member 'comments' in something not a structure or union`.

I am afraid I have a fundamental misconception about dynamic typing, but I hope it's something much simpler.

Comment: How have you declared your `currentEvent` property? Also, you have a terrible memory leak in the code you posted.  You assign an owned object to `currentEvent` and then immediately overwrite it (and leak it) with the retained `e`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some problems with your setter: (1) don't call the getter (self.currentEvent) when releasing the ivar, (2) always retain the new obj *before* releasing the old obj, in case it is the same obj, ie:

```
-(void)setCurrentEvent:(id)e {
    [e retain];
    [currentEvent release];
    currentEvent = e;
}
```

That aside, I don't understand what your trying to do with dynamic typing.

This line will cause a compiler warning because you've told it that currentEvent is an id, which doesn't have a comments member, so it rightly complains:

```
return [currentEvent.comments count];
```

If somehow you know that the id currentEvent is actually an object of a particular class that has a comments you can cast the id to another type to avoid the warning:

```
return [(CommentEvent*)currentEvent.comments count];
```

But before you do that, how do you know?  You could check to see if it is the right class:

```
if ([currentEvent isKindOfClass:[CommentEvent class]]) {
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the corrections to the setter. I am at a point where I can accomplish most of the things I want and need to, but still feel sometimes that I lack some basic understanding of Objective-C concepts which causes me to get basics like this not quite right. 

On the dynamic typing -- I was trying to avoid writing almost the same code twice, but realized that I would be much better off going back to the two classes that are similar and rewrite them so that I can use the same class for the two types of objects.

Thanks for the `isKindOfClass` suggestion too.